# error recompiling "sharp" for electron

Tags: node.js, electron, node-gyp, nodemon, sharp

I am trying to run `electron-rebuild sharp` so that I can use the [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) package in electron.

I also need to have the [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) package and when I have both these packages installed I get the following error:

```
electron-rebuild searching for .node file /home/derek/projects/fsevents-test/node_modules/fsevents/build/Release +3ms
electron-rebuild testing files [ '.deps', '.forge-meta', '.node', 'obj.target' ] +1ms
✖ Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
Path must be a string. Received undefined
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1167:7)
    at Rebuilder.<anonymous> (/home/derek/projects/realfood/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/rebuild.js:151:35)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/derek/projects/realfood/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/rebuild.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
```

If I run the command again then this error does not occur and the package is rebuilt and I can use it.

It looks like it is something to do fsevents - I am on linux so that shouldn't be used.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Using node 8.1.2 and npm 5.0.3

Answer (score 0):

OK this isn't a great solution but if you get stuck with this it will let you proceed.

You can stop `electron-rebuild` from trying to compile fsevents by removing the `binding.gyp` file:

```
rm -f node_modules/fsevents/binding.gyp
```

you will then be able to run `electron-rebuild` without getting any errors